# How to calculate average rating of my product in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

This is the query I used to get the average of rating, but the result was null:

```
db.products.aggregate([{$unwind: "$reviews"}, {$group: {_id: "$reviews", ratingAvg: {$avg: "$rating"}}}])
```

This is my product schema:

```
    category: String,
    name: String,
    price: Number,
    image: String,
    description: String,
    stock: Number,
    reviews: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID, ref: 'Review'
        }
})
```

This is my review schema:

```
    text: String,
    rating: Number,
    // author: {
    //  id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID, ref: 'User'},
    //  name: String
    // }
    author: String
})
```

Every time I run this query I get:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f79d1b4b4b3c1061f1fbe52"), "ratingAvg" : null }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f79d1a5b4b3c1061f1fbe51"), "ratingAvg" : null }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f79d196b4b3c1061f1fbe4f"), "ratingAvg" : null }
```

It is showing ratingAvg as"null" whereas I have ratings for that product in my database.

Comment: You unwinded the array,  Its being an object. So you need to call the rating using dot annotation. Working  https://mongoplayground.net/p/Hw37KjNCP4T

Comment: I want the average of all the ratings of a product. This gives the average for the same text. And also I tried this but didn't work, it still showed null.

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/3ss0LOlkAgf does this help you

Comment: nope didn't work

Comment: If you dont tell me what is the issue, how can i help you? Provide your sample data and expected output. Else you can try with what i gave you

Comment: (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cYFxDV91in_rsBOZNEiyt8wiz804O4YTMnfMWaupe8A/edit?usp=sharing) Check this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$lookup` helps to join two collections.

```
[
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Review",
      "localField": "reviews",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "reviews"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$reviews"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      ratingAvg: {
        $avg: "$reviews.rating"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Then you can easily find the average using `$avg` along with `$group` after destructure the array using `$uniwnd`

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JHXYJ9Of_wM)**